# Adjointenes of unknown functors

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, accessible-categories

I would like to understand what are [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n9/n9.pdf) on the page $266$
the types of items in the adjoint euqation $$\mu^{Lim}_{\cal K}\vdash Lim\ \eta_{\cal K}^{Lim}.$$ 
They should be functors by the definition of $\vdash.$ From where to where they lead and how do they act ?

Comment: The paper says that $Lim$ is a pseudomonad on $CAT$, which should already tell you what are the domains and codomains of these functors. Did you look at the references mentioned there ?

Comment: @ArnaudD. The paper is far too complicated for me to read, therefore I've asked for help. So the target is $CAT$ by what you write . What is the domain ?

Comment: My understanding is that $Lim$ is a $2$-functor $CAT\to CAT$. $\mu^{Lim}_{\mathcal{K}}$ should be a functor $Lim(Lim(\mathcal{K}))\to Lim(\mathcal{K})$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. How $Lim$ acts on $\cal K \to L$ in $CAT$ ? And what is a $2$-functor technically ?

Comment: Regarding 2-functors, for a quick reference, the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-functor) might help. [This survey](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-functor) and [this recent book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.06055.pdf) could also be useful for more details about 2-category theory.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Still cannot find there how acts $Lim$ on $\cal K\to L$.

Comment: The nLab has some explanations for the [dual case](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cocompletion).

Comment: @user122424 "The paper is far too complicated for me to read, therefore I've asked for help." Indeed! Many of your questions on this site ask for people to explain bits of notation or language buried deep within technical papers. Reading these papers requires you to understand far more complicated conceptual matters than the bits of notation you're asking about. I wonder what the point is...